# Выгрузка циклом while perl данных SQL-запроса в excel

Tags: perl

Имеется сайт на Apace с отчетами. Работник вводит на страничке даты "с" и "по" и жмет кнопку "показать".

Далее запускается скрипт Perl, в котором идет подключение к БД Oracle, далее в этом скрипте запуск select и вывод результата на страницу.

Требуется сделать так, чтобы данный отчет также выгружался в excel-файл.

Я установил модуль use Excel::Writer::XLSX; и простейший файл excel формируется в папку без проблем.

Требуется сделать чтобы n-строк моего sql-запроса с девятью полями выгружались в excel. Сейчас файл пустой, но в браузере показывает всю информацию.

```
while($sth->fetch()) {
    print qq|\n\t\t<tr><td>$n1</td><td>$n2</td><td>$n3</td><td>$n4</td><td>$n5</td><td>$n6</td><td>$n7</td><td>$n8</td><td>$n9</td></tr>|;
    $worksheet->write(1,1,$n1,$n2,$n3,$n4,$n5,$n6,$n7,$n8,$n9);
}
```

Comment: Я установил модуль use Excel::Writer::XLSX; и простейший файл excel формируется в папку без проблем.

Comment: Требуется сделать чтобы n-строк моего sql-запроса с девятью полями выгружались в excel. Сейчас файл пустой, но в браузере показывает всю информацию.

Comment: while($sth->fetch())  {
 print qq|\n\t\t<tr><td>$n1</td><td>$n2</td><td>$n3</td><td>$n4</td><td>$n5</td><td>$n6</td><td>$n7</td><td>$n8</td><td>$n9</td></tr>|;
 $worksheet->write(1,1,$n1,$n2,$n3,$n4,$n5,$n6,$n7,$n8,$n9);
}